# How do I transfer a message to a string in discord.py

Tags: python, discord

Im trying to know how to make the bot remember the message a user send $equal message that user will say, and when the user says $message the bot will say the message the user send on $equal message that user will say.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please include your code, approaches and errors you face. You may also take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Should this only be a normal `say` command? What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

It's really hard to understand what you want to achieve. Please add more description to your question, but even though I think you want to achieve something like this (if not add a further explanation and I'll try to help):

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user: #returning when the author of message is bot
        return
    
    msg = message.content #getting content of user's message
    await message.channel.send(msg) #sending a message user sent

    await client.process_commands(message) #proccesing commands (without this your @client.command won't work)
```

**Remember that you have to enable [intents.messages](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?#discord.Intents).**

[Discord.py Documentation - on_message() event](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?#discord.on_message)

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a complement to @RiveN 's answer.

```
keywords = ["um", "keyboard"]
grab_top = ["top", "t"]

@client.event
async def on_message(msg):
    if msg.author == client.user:
        return

    if msg.content in keywords:
        await msg.channel.send('This is a keyword')
        
    if msg.content in grab_top:
        await scrape_website()
        
    if msg.content.startswith("~test()"):
        await msg.channel.send('This is our test')
```

inside of discord:

```
Me: ~test()

Quaint Faint Saint BOT: 
This is our test

Me: um

Quaint Faint Saint BOT: 
This is a keyword
```